ffmpeg cannot find default config file
I downloaded the full build of ffmpeg from gyan.dev;
When running more complex filters, etc... I find some options throws errors.
For example:

ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vf "drawtext=text='My watermark':fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:x=100:y=100" -c:a copy "output.mp4"

Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
How to specify the 'default config file' ?
If it helps, the details of the build are:
>ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2024-09-26-git-f43916e217-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvvenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-liblc3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      59. 40.100 / 59. 40.100
libavcodec     61. 20.100 / 61. 20.100
libavformat    61.  8.100 / 61.  8.100
libavdevice    61.  4.100 / 61.  4.100
libavfilter    10.  5.100 / 10.  5.100
libswscale      8.  4.100 /  8.  4.100
libswresample   5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libpostproc    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100


fontconfig was originally developed for linux and Unix-like systems, where a system-wide font configuration file was usually stored in /etc/fonts/. That's not the case on Windows. But it's not a fatal error - the filter will just use a default font (e.g. Arial). Or you can specify a custom font using a path like fontfile=C\:/Windows/fonts/Arial.ttf

It may not display a fatal error, but it also does NOT produce any output file;
I get 'Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)' and that's it.
I was previously using 'essentials build' (2022) and it produced an output file;
After switching to full version as shown above, no output is produced.

Ok, that is not directly connected to the filter. Add -report and rerun.
